# Multiple version of same plugin on one jenkins master

Tags: jenkins

I have a query I am a bit new to Jenkins hence trying to understand things.
So suppose I have a job name "First" that is using a particular plugin say x with version 1.2.2

Now I update the plugin x to 1.2.5
Create a new job name "Second" that using version 1.2.5

Now what happens to Job "first" will it keep using the old version of the plugin
Also, I got to know that the job details are stored in an XML file so what will be the plugin version detail in there will it be the old one or the new one?

Comment: The Job "First" will now use version 1.2.5 of the plugin x. Also, if you have two questions (which it seems you do), please post them as separate individual questions.

Comment: Jenkins can only consume one version of a plugin. They are installed on the master/controller, available to all jobs. It would probably even fail to re/start if you dropped 2 versions into the plugin dir! The stored ver. ref. is updated when you run or save job First. Change your plugin to use parameters or flags to alter behaviour.